# Pylint symbols and line numbering issue

Tags: vimrc, plugin-powerline

[image: Symbols and line numbering problem]

I have an issue as the image shows where the linting symbols on the left are corrupted. I can't find why this happens. But it appears only in python scripts. I suppose this has something to do with the linter and the symbols. I am using the gruvbox scheme along with jedi-vim and the powerline symbols. Has anyone dealt with a similar issue before?

```
filetype plugin indent on   " load filetype-specific indent files


" minimalist
" set t_Co=256
let g:gruvbox_italic=0
colorscheme gruvbox 
set background=dark
let g:airline_theme='angr'
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark='medium'

" UltiSnips
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"

" JS syntastic fix
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0 " Allow JSX in normal JS files
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']

" Force jedi to work with py3
let g:jedi#force_py_version = 3

" vim-commentary
autocmd FileType c   setlocal commentstring=//\ %s
autocmd FileType cpp setlocal commentstring=//\ %s

""" automatically change working directory to the directory of the current file
autocmd BufEnter * if expand('%:p') !~ '://' | :lcd %:p:h | endif

" Ignore pyc files
let NERDTreeIgnore=['\.pyc$', '\~$'] "ignore files in NERDTree

" Python syntax highlight
let python_highlight_all = 1
let python_no_operator_highlight = 1
let g:python_highlight_class_vars = 1

" DoxyGen-Syntax
let g:load_doxygen_syntax = 1

""" NERD Tree
" show hidden files
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1


" Ack
if executable('ag')
    let g:ackprg = 'ag --vimgrep'
endif

" Ale
" Signs
let g:ale_sign_error = '❌'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '❗'

"Echoed message
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'E'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'W'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '[%linter%] %s [%severity%]'

"Linters
" let g:ale_linters = {
" \   'c': ['clangd', 'uncrustify'],
" \   'python': ['flake8'],
" \}

" Syntastic settings for linting
" set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
" set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
" set statusline+=%*

" let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
" let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
" let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
" let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

" let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8']

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Filetype settings
" C
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.h set filetype=c

" CSS
autocmd FileType css setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

" HTML
autocmd FileType html setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

" ino Arduino sketches
autocmd FileType ino setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

" JavaScript
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

" JSON
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set filetype=json

" make
" makefiles require tabs for indentation
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab

" Markdown
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown

" Python
autocmd FileType py setlocal textwidth=79 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab autoindent

" SQL
autocmd FileType sql setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

" yaml
" yaml files require spaces for indentation
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal tabstop=2 softtabstop=2 shiftwidth=2

""" strip trailing whitespace
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces
" http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/
function! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    " Preparation :save last search, and cursor position.
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    " Do the business:
    %s/\s\+$//e
    " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

" strip trailing whitespace on save
" NOTE
" order file extensions alphabetically
autocmd BufWritePre *.c,*.css,*.cu,*.h,*.html,*.ino,*.md,*.markdown,*.js,*.py,*.sh,*.sql,*.tex,*.txt :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

This is my `line.vimrc` script which is loaded in the `.vimrc` file. I think the problem lies in the following lines from `line.vimrc` script and the mixture of syntastic and the configurations.

```
let g:ale_sign_error = '❌'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '❗'
```

Comment: In the current state of your question it will be hard for us to debug your problem. You should begin with identifying what is causing the problem: try to reduce your plugins to the minimum to get this behavior, try another colorscheme, try disabling your settings (see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)). Then you can update your question with the new information you gathered and you can also contact the plugin maintainer (if you find that the problem is caused by a specific plugin) using the issue tracker of its plugin on github.

Comment: I have edited the post. The provided link you mention is really useful.